# Entity framework core one-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-core

I have two models DestinationEntity and SourceEntity, what I want is in view I need to  get destination details first, after that I need to get source details in that I want to select multiple destinations and save both have separate CRUD entry, how can I achieve this

source can have multiple destination and destination can have single source

here is my entities

```
public class DestinationEntity
{
public int ID {get; set;}
public string DName {get; set;}
public string DPath {get; set;}

public SourceEntity source {get; set;} 
}

public class SourceEntity
{
public int ID {get; set;}
public string SName {get; set;}
public string SPath {get; set;}

public ICollection<DestinationEntity> Destinations {get; set;} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and Delete are pretty obvious, Update is the tricky one.  Basically, there are three approaches.  Since each Destination MUST have one and only one Source.

One, remove all Destinations and then re-add them to the Source.  This removes "orphaned" Destinations and is the simplest, brute force approach.

Two, have the UI communicate which Destinations are added and which are removed. OR, detect it yourself by examining the FKs (null = new) in the input and compare existing with saved values, removing the "deleted" Destinations.  Trickier.

Three, use the JSONPatchDocument format which gives a roadmap on how to update the saved entities.